# Remove old SQL Server from SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server

my current SharePoint Foundation 2013 is connected to SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have moved all databases to my new SQL Server 2014 successfully by following below article.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/move-all-databases

Everything is good except my old SQL server is still showing in "Servers in Farm" page (Central Administration, System Settings, Manage servers in this farm)

I see "Remove Server" link but when I click on it, I get following error. How to remove my old SQL server completely from SharePoint farm? Thanks.

```
An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPDatabaseServiceInstance", could not be deleted because other objects depend on it.
Update all of these dependants to point to null or different objects and retry this operation.
The dependant objects are as follows: SPWebService Name=WSS_Administration SPWebService
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Administration and Config database connection strings cannot change, the 'old' SQL Server entry will always remain as your SQL Alias is using it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Trevor, the 'old' SQL Server entry will always remain as your SQL Alias is using it.

You don't need to remove the SQL server, you need to point the web application to the new database server by setting up SQL Server connection aliases.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/move-all-databases?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-point-the-web-application-to-the-new-database-server-by-setting-up-sql-server-connection-aliases

Install & configure SharePoint 2013 with SQL Client Alias for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sowmyancs/install-configure-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-client-alias